# Get user and claims as an administrator of a client

Tags: identityserver4

Is it possible to get user identity from ID4 as an administrator.

For example, Bob logs in and consents to access "My Movie App". When Bob logs in, his clientid and profile are saved independently into the My Movie App DB.

Later, the "My Movie App" needs to contact bob at bobs email or phone because bob forgot to pay and accounting is now catching up. However, Bob has changed his email and phone with the identity provider.

The "My Movie App" has Bobs clientid but would like to ask identity server if there are any changes to Bobs profile before it generates the Past Due contacts list.

Is there a way to get clients new profile without having Bobs user name and password but having only the userid or clientid?

Is there a way to ask Identity Server to see a list of Customers that have consented to using "My Movie App"?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the source code and poking around I believe the answer is you must extend ID4 itself.

For example, you can extend users to hold information such as ADMIN and when you log into ID4 directly you could use that information to authorize a controller.

Keep in mind that one instance of ID4 is designed be used by multiple companies.

URL Path could like this: 
http://myid4:5000/BusinessName/MyMoviePhoneApp/GetCustomers

The Controller could be tagged with [Authorize(Admin)] and return json result of Customers.